# Can you automatically close safari and chrome incognito windows when your Mac runs out of battery?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, laptop, privacy

Their have been multiple times I've been on incognito on google chrome and safari online and then I fall asleep to then wake up to my Mac dead out of charge, what I've found is once I've charge my Mac and I'm able to log back into my user the incognito window is still running, it doesn't automatically close like it does when you log out.

You can even try this experiment for yourself if your Mac on a low percentage of charge right now, open a incognito window, put on a youtube video or something in that window, let your Mac die, then charge it back up, log back into your user, and the window will still be there.

Is their a command I can put in that closes my incognito chrome and safari windows when my Mac runs out of charge? Or maybe even an app?

I've tried searching this question but couldn't find any answers. Thanks :)

Comment: Set your MAC power management to Suspend at 20% or 25% so that it does not shut off.  Unceremonious shut down does not usually issue commands to clean things up during the shut down.

Comment: @John Do you mind linking me to a tutorial on how to "Set your MAC power management to Suspend at 20% or 25%"  or giving some directions please? I went to System Prefences > Energy Saver, and don't see any option like that there. I'm not too tech savvy haha thanks :)

Comment: Try this Apple article:   https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/mac-help/mchle41a6ccd/11.0/mac/11.0 . That should work.

Comment: @John That article does not mention anything about Setting my MAC power management to Suspend at 20% or 25%.

Comment: It says "You can set your Mac to go to sleep after a specified duration of inactivity."  So keep the machine at a reasonable charge and suspend after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1610871  <-- Specific percentage is not user adjustable, so you will need the workaround I suggested.

Comment: YouTube will be generating a keep-alive, I would guess, which will bypass any other management. Check Activity Monitor, CPU or Memory tab & right click the top of the columns. Add 'Preventing Sleep' & click that column twice to sort 'yes' to the top. Ignore `hidd` which will go away of its own accord when sleep should be called (as will many other root processes). See what else is preventing it. Test with a YouTube video running too.

Comment: @John What was the workaround you suggested on discussions.apple.com/thread/1610871  ? are you the user "Courcoul"? or are you just referring to the link to say it isnt adjustable

Comment: You can't 'suspend after inactivity' because as I previously mentioned, something is intentionally keeping it awake. You need to find & quit that process. If it does try to hibernate at low battery (which it should)  & fails, then suspect your battery needs replacing.